# R: How to combine two correlation matrices using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two corr matrices that I would like to combine in 1 plot:

**Sample code for Corr Matrix 1:**

```
matrix_values <- c(-0.07, -0.03, 0.1, 0.11, 0.06, 0.16, 0.16, 0.13, 0.04, 0.06, 0.05, 0.04, 0.16, 0.07, 0.1, 0.08, 0.08, 0.17, 0.07, -0.13, 0.16, -0.07, 0.09, 0.07, -0.08, 0, 0.09, -0.02, 0.18, 0.09, 0.01, -0.1, -0.04, -0.12, -0.03, 0.03, 0.09, 0.09, 0.15, -0.01, 0.15, 0.09, 0.11, 0.09, 0.15, 0.19, -0.07, -0.04, 0, -0.12, NaN, -0.02, -0.11, 0.01, 0.1, -0.1, -0.1, 0.01, 0.04, 0.08, -0.02, -0.12, 0.09, -0.05, -0.07, -0.03, -0.19, -0.07, -0.16, -0.08, -0.05, -0.04, 0.03, -0.09, -0.09, -0.12, -0.07, 0.04, 0.07, 0.04, 0.02, -0.08, -0.03, -0.18, -0.02, 0.03, -0.06, 0.03, -0.07, 0.09, 0.04, -0.06, -0.1, -0.07, 0.1, 0.02, 0.06, -0.13, -0.14, -0.06, NaN, NaN, -0.07, -0.12, 0.02, -0.02, 0.01, 0.02, -0.01, -0.08, -0.03, -0.06, -0.05, -0.15, 0, -0.12, 0.13, -0.09, -0.05, 0.05, 0.08, -0.06, 0.16, 0.16, 0, 0.06, -0.05, -0.05, 0.14, -0.02, 0.12, 0.01, -0.07, -0.06, 0.07, 0.07, -0.13, 0.06, -0.05, -0.06, -0.15, -0.07, 0.11, 0.03, 0.1, 0.05, -0.12, 0.13, -0.1, 0.04, NaN, NaN, NaN, -0.03, -0.12, -0.02, 0.23, 0.13, 0.04, 0.01, 0.1, -0.01, 0.04, 0.03, -0.02, 0, -0.01, -0.08, -0.17, -0.05, 0, -0.07, -0.13, 0.1, -0.04, -0.01, 0.05, -0.03, -0.03, 0.13, -0.03, 0.01, 0.03, -0.03, 0.06, -0.01, -0.08, 0.05, 0.12, 0.09, 0.08, 0.07, -0.04, 0.09, 0.05, 0.1, 0.03, 0.05, 0.09, 0, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.03, -0.03, 0.13, 0.14, 0.04, -0.03, 0.05, 0.14, 0.02, 0, -0.09, 0, 0, 0.01, -0.1, -0.14, 0, 0.02, 0.04, -0.07, -0.03, -0.07, -0.08, 0.1, 0.02, 0.18, 0.07, -0.16, 0.08, 0.03, -0.01, 0.03, -0.01, -0.07, 0.01, 0.1, 0.11, -0.11, 0.04, -0.08, -0.01, -0.03, -0.02, 0.09, 0.03, 0.13, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, -0.01, -0.05, 0.24, 0.02, 0, 0.11, 0.22, 0.22, 0.09, 0.06, 0.1, 0.09, 0.21, 0.16, 0.08, 0.08, 0.14, 0.05, 0.14, 0.15, -0.01, 0.05, 0.23, 0.13, 0.04, 0.06, 0.11, 0.05, 0.16, 0.03, 0.06, 0.01, -0.02, 0.23, -0.05, -0.09, 0.01, -0.02, 0.08, -0.07, 0.06, -0.01, -0.02, -0.03, 0.06, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.05, -0.02, 0.08, -0.03, 0.02, -0.05, 0.13, 0.08, 0.08, 0.11, -0.04, -0.08, 0.03, 0.09, 0.1, -0.04, 0.12, 0.12, -0.06, 0.07, -0.09, 0.03, 0.03, -0.03, -0.02, 0.05, 0.04, -0.14, -0.05, 0.15, 0.06, -0.03, 0.04, -0.06, 0.21, 0.12, 0.2, -0.04, 0.05, 0.02, 0.14, 0, 0.12, 0.04, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.13, 0, 0.12, 0.13, 0.05, 0.03, 0.09, 0.13, -0.05, 0.1, 0.14, 0.05, 0.06, 0.11, 0.03, 0.09, 0.17, 0.04, 0.15, 0.03, 0.03, -0.1, 0.07, 0.01, 0.02, 0.04, -0.08, 0.06, 0.05, 0.14, 0.07, 0.03, 0, 0.14, 0.02, -0.01, 0.02, 0.13, 0.09, -0.16, 0.1, -0.06, -0.04, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, -0.14, -0.05, 0.2, 0.05, -0.07, 0.1, 0.21, 0.14, -0.04, 0.01, 0.11, 0.1, 0.17, 0.21, 0.06, 0.09, 0.17, 0.17, 0.26, -0.04, 0.04, -0.01, 0.06, 0.14, -0.11, 0.05, 0.13, -0.05, 0.14, 0.06, 0.01, -0.05, 0.03, 0.04, 0.02, -0.08, -0.09, 0, -0.08, -0.21, -0.02, -0.03, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, -0.16, -0.1, 0.03, 0.06, 0.03, 0.16, 0.07, 0.09, -0.05, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.15, 0.04, 0.11, 0.04, 0.03, 0.08, 0.1, 0.06, -0.09, -0.03, 0.25, 0.11, -0.12, -0.12, 0.07, 0.03, 0.12, 0.11, 0.07, -0.07, 0.1, 0.11, -0.08, -0.05, -0.1, 0.1, -0.04, 0.07, 0.07, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, -0.06, -0.04, 0.19, 0.04, -0.04, 0.07, 0.09, 0.07, -0.04, 0.03, 0.06, 0.1, 0.01, 0, 0.16, -0.07, 0.12, 0.07, 0.11, 0, 0.02, 0.17, 0.19, 0.13, -0.15, -0.14, 0.26, 0.08, 0.02, 0.08, 0.17, -0.03, -0.02, 0.17, 0.03, 0.03, -0.1, 0.1, -0.02, -0.2, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, -0.02, 0.15, -0.01, -0.02, -0.19, 0, 0.05, -0.08, -0.09, -0.15, 0.16, 0.12, 0.08, -0.03, 0.11, 0.09, 0.08, 0.06, 0.11, -0.07, 0.2, 0.05, 0.22, 0.05, -0.1, -0.07, -0.08, 0.07, 0.18, -0.06, 0.12, -0.06, -0.06, 0.09, -0.12, -0.15, -0.16, 0, -0.21, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, -0.07, -0.1, 0.23, -0.08, 0.01, -0.02, 0.13, 0.13, -0.04, 0.14, 0.03, 0.14, 0.07, 0.15, -0.02, 0.01, 0.05, 0.03, 0, 0.15, -0.15, 0.1, 0.11, 0.17, 0, -0.06, 0.14, -0.14, 0.03, 0.16, -0.12, -0.15, -0.1, 0.17, 0.2, -0.13, -0.11, -0.11, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.02, 0, 0.13, 0.03, -0.04, 0.03, 0.06, -0.08, -0.11, -0.08, -0.09, 0.12, 0.1, -0.01, 0.04, -0.12, -0.1, 0.01, 0.09, 0.02, 0.04, -0.03, 0.04, 0.11, -0.11, -0.15, 0.07, -0.13, -0.05, 0.15, 0.02, -0.07, 0.12, 0, 0.06, -0.05, 0.09, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, -0.25, -0.05, 0.29, -0.04, -0.06, 0.11, 0.16, 0.07, 0.05, 0.06, 0.12, 0.09, 0.22, 0.11, 0.17, 0.1, 0.19, 0.12, 0.17, 0.03, 0.03, 0.11, 0.19, 0.17, 0.02, 0.07, 0.27, -0.02, -0.05, 0.19, 0.16, 0, 0.11, 0.14, 0.04, 0.14, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, -0.12, -0.08, 0.36, -0.08, 0.02, -0.03, -0.04, 0, -0.14, 0.02, -0.07, 0.05, 0.01, 0.03, -0.06, -0.03, 0.04, -0.05, 0.15, -0.03, -0.2, 0.03, 0.01, 0.1, 0.15, 0.21, 0.02, -0.2, -0.03, -0.01, -0.1, 0.02, 0.05, 0.1, -0.11, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, -0.04, 0.08, 0.2, -0.06, 0.06, 0.12, 0.2, 0.12, 0.03, 0.06, 0.08, 0.12, 0.16, 0.11, 0.15, 0.18, 0.1, 0.09, 0.04, 0.11, 0.03, 0.06, 0.11, -0.05, -0.06, 0.04, 0.04, -0.06, 0.11, 0.18, 0.12, -0.06, -0.06, 0.13, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.09, 0.04, -0.05, 0.12, 0.13, 0.13, 0.13, 0.07, 0.16, 0.05, 0.07, -0.1, 0.08, -0.05, -0.01, -0.06, -0.07, 0.01, -0.07, -0.05, 0.13, -0.06, -0.01, -0.07, -0.06, -0.02, 0.11, -0.07, 0.13, -0.02, -0.03, 0.03, -0.09, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, -0.13, -0.12, 0.07, -0.03, -0.03, -0.06, -0.1, 0.04, -0.12, 0.07, -0.04, -0.08, -0.16, -0.03, -0.11, -0.24, -0.08, -0.04, -0.04, -0.13, -0.19, -0.01, -0.01, 0, -0.08, -0.03, -0.06, -0.15, -0.11, -0.05, -0.05, -0.02, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, -0.18, -0.13, 0.03, 0.09, -0.03, -0.09, 0.14, 0.02, 0, 0.05, -0.11, -0.08, 0.04, -0.04, -0.03, -0.16, 0.01, -0.03, 0.11, -0.11, -0.1, 0.02, 0.01, 0.06, -0.05, -0.01, 0.15, -0.05, 0.08, 0.01, -0.07, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, -0.04, -0.13, 0.13, 0.15, 0.23, 0.23, 0.13, 0.1, 0.01, 0.04, 0.04, 0.08, 0.09, 0.08, 0.03, 0.03, 0.13, 0.14, 0.04, 0.01, 0.09, -0.03, 0.12, 0.01, -0.06, -0.11, 0.09, -0.13, 0.02, 0.17, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.07, 0.11, 0.09, -0.08, 0.01, -0.04, 0.05, 0.16, -0.03, 0.08, 0.02, 0.05, -0.11, 0.1, 0.01, -0.07, 0.05, 0, 0.05, 0.09, -0.22, -0.09, 0.05, -0.05, -0.05, -0.04, -0.02, -0.11, -0.09, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.24, 0.07, 0.05, 0.07, 0.11, -0.11, -0.08, -0.16, -0.13, -0.07, -0.03, 0.01, -0.06, -0.07, -0.01, -0.07, 0.04, 0.04, -0.1, -0.04, 0.06, 0.04, 0.16, 0.08, -0.05, -0.09, 0.13, 0.14, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, -0.04, 0.01, 0, 0.05, 0, 0.07, -0.02, -0.06, -0.07, -0.12, -0.02, 0.08, -0.01, -0.07, -0.14, -0.11, -0.14, -0.04, 0.01, -0.15, 0.15, -0.15, -0.02, 0.02, -0.14, -0.1, -0.06, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.14, 0.08, 0.34, 0.02, 0.16, 0.04, 0.12, 0.21, 0.03, 0.07, 0.18, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0, 0.02, 0.05, 0.1, 0.01, -0.05, -0.07, 0.08, -0.08, -0.02, -0.01, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, -0.06, -0.12, -0.02, 0.06, 0.08, -0.11, -0.05, -0.07, -0.06, -0.08, -0.12, 0, -0.03, -0.08, -0.11, -0.17, -0.02, -0.05, 0.01, -0.15, -0.21, -0.03, -0.04, 0.03, -0.03, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, -0.02, -0.07, -0.03, 0.02, -0.08, -0.1, -0.08, -0.01, -0.07, -0.02, -0.15, 0.04, -0.07, -0.04, -0.22, -0.09, -0.1, -0.02, -0.14, -0.15, -0.22, -0.06, -0.07, 0.04, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.09, -0.04, 0.02, 0.14, 0.15, 0.13, 0.02, 0.07, -0.01, 0.08, 0.1, -0.13, 0.1, -0.02, 0.02, 0.01, 0.05, 0.07, -0.07, 0.01, 0.04, -0.13, 0.04, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.06, 0.14, 0.07, 0.15, 0.1, 0.09, 0.14, 0.09, 0.03, 0.04, 0.13, 0.02, 0.13, -0.02, 0.21, -0.03, 0.03, 0.12, -0.06, 0.08, 0.13, 0.01, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.04, -0.09, 0.08, 0.01, 0.04, 0.01, 0, 0.06, 0.04, 0.03, 0.09, -0.12, -0.06, -0.01, -0.09, -0.11, -0.07, -0.04, -0.05, -0.1, 0.01, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.12, 0.09, -0.05, 0, 0.08, 0.02, -0.08, -0.15, -0.14, -0.16, 0.03, 0, -0.03, -0.11, 0.04, -0.09, -0.17, -0.09, -0.05, -0.05, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, -0.07, -0.07, 0.09, -0.07, 0.07, 0.05, 0.06, 0.23, 0, 0.11, -0.01, 0.03, 0.04, 0.07, 0.04, -0.01, 0.01, 0.04, -0.03, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, -0.03, -0.15, -0.01, 0.14, 0.19, 0.03, -0.1, -0.03, -0.12, 0.04, -0.14, 0.05, -0.15, -0.09, 0.03, -0.16, 0.05, 0.12, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, -0.08, -0.05, 0.09, -0.08, 0.09, 0.05, 0.08, 0.05, -0.08, 0.03, -0.04, 0.06, -0.15, 0.06, 0.07, 0.09, 0.01, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, -0.02, 0.04, 0.1, -0.16, 0.05, 0, 0.06, 0.06, -0.05, -0.01, -0.13, 0.11, -0.1, 0.03, 0.08, -0.09, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.02, -0.18, -0.11, 0.02, 0.06, 0.01, -0.18, -0.03, -0.19, -0.01, -0.23, 0.02, -0.11, -0.06, 0.03, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, -0.04, -0.07, 0.07, 0.09, 0.08, 0.1, 0.06, 0.12, -0.06, -0.04, 0.12, 0.14, -0.03, 0.04, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0, -0.01, 0.23, -0.09, 0.1, -0.07, -0.01, 0.13, -0.05, 0.07, -0.11, 0.01, -0.17, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.1, 0.04, 0.05, -0.06, 0.17, 0, -0.03, 0.01, -0.14, 0.08, -0.05, 0.16, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.03, 0.04, -0.1, 0.1, 0.17, 0.12, 0.19, 0.1, 0.24, 0.15, 0.03, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0, 0.13, -0.11, -0.02, 0.14, 0.01, -0.07, -0.07, -0.08, -0.1, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.1, 0.07, 0.19, -0.06, 0.12, -0.09, 0.13, 0.2, -0.16, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0, 0.06, 0.04, -0.19, 0.05, -0.08, 0, 0.04, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.03, 0.1, 0.17, -0.03, 0.05, 0.01, 0.25, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.11, 0.15, 0.13, -0.11, 0.16, 0.05, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.05, 0.06, 0.1, 0.06, 0.18, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.09, 0.02, 0.3, 0.11, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.02, 0.06, 0.21, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.01, -0.01, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, -0.21, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN)

 cor_matrix1 <- matrix(matrix_values, ncol = 51, nrow = 51)
 dat <- melt(cor_matrix1[-52, ])


  r <- ggplot(data =  dat, aes(x = Var1, y = Var2)) +
   geom_tile(aes(fill = value), color = "white") +
   scale_fill_gradientn(values=c(1, .6, .5, .4, 0), colours=c("#770000", "red", "#ff8000", "#ffff00", "#ffffe5"))+
   theme( axis.title.x = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y = element_blank(),
   panel.background = element_blank())
```

**Sample code for Corr Matrix 2:**

```
 cor_matrix2 <- matrix(matrix_values, ncol = 51, nrow = 51)
 dat <- melt(cor_matrix2[-52, ])
 p <- ggplot(data =  dat, aes(x = Var1, y = Var2)) +
 geom_tile(aes(fill = value), color = "white") +
scale_fill_gradientn(values=c(1, .6, .5, .4, 0), colours=c("#00007f", "#1212b2", "cyan", "#b4b4cc", "white"))
```

[image: 1) combine the _r_ and _p_ matrices so that _r_ shows up in the lower diagonal and _p_ in the upper diagonnal; 2) have the main diagonal to be a *black* line (a line that separates the two matrices); 3)certain values can be highlighted]

Comment: You will need to combine the data before plotting, but having multiple legends for the same thing is not easy to do in ggplot. Furthermore, why do they need to go in the same plot when they have different ranges/represent different entities?

Comment: They represents data from 2 different populations and I want to have them side by side for easy comparison. How can I have multiple legends? A sample code is highly appreciated!

Comment: Also how can I have the diagonal in black and fixed (min, max) range for my c values? and also how can I highlight some values in the matrix (i.e. black hollow rectangles)?

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, ggplot does not let you use multiple colour scales for the same plot. It also makes your graph harder to interpret. However, you can get clever with shapes:

Some preprocessing to handle your data, I'm sure you can avoid some of this when generating your dataset:

```
cor_matrix1 <- matrix(matrix_values, ncol = 51, nrow = 51)
 dat1 <- melt(cor_matrix1[-52, ])
 cor_matrix2 <- matrix(matrix_values, ncol = 51, nrow = 51)
 dat2 <- melt(cor_matrix2[-52, ])
 dat2$Var1 <- 52 - dat2$Var1
 dat2$Var2 <- 52 - dat2$Var2
 dat1$Class <- "A"
 dat2$Class <- "B"
 dat <- rbind(dat1,dat2)
 dat <- dat[!is.nan(dat$value),]
```

Instead of using `geom_tile`, try `geom_point`. This will give you the flexibility to use shapes. (I.e. an additional dimension on which to segment data):

```
   ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = Var1, y = Var2)) +
   geom_point(size = 4, aes(color = value, pch = Class)) +
   scale_color_gradientn(values=c(1, .6, .5, .4, 0), colours=c("#00007f", "#1212b2", "cyan", "#b4b4cc", "white")) + 
   geom_abline(slope = -1,intercept = 52 , size = 2) + 
    geom_rect(xmin = 30, xmax = 31, ymin = 30, ymax = 31, color = "red", fill = NA) + 
     theme( axis.title.x = element_blank(),
            axis.title.y = element_blank(),
            panel.background = element_blank())
```

Which gives:

[image]

A couple of things going on here:

- The `pch` argument to `geom_point` sets a different shape for each population
- `geom_abline` gives you the black line down the center of the graph (you can also do this with points, but I think this is clearer
- The `geom_rect` argument creates the red rectangle. Adjust the mins/maxes as needed and put in as many as you need.

Also, note that negative correlations here are going to white (as per the color scale you defined). I would find this misleading.